# remove an .append() to return an element to it's original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm loading up a `ul` for a image slider but I need to remove the images (`ul`) and revert back to the original state (before javascript manipulations) when the slider is closed because I will later need to reload the ul for another set of different images.

Here is how I'm loading the slider.

```
 var get_images = [ "show_1.jpg", "show_2.jpg", "show_3.jpg", "show_4.jpg"];

 $.each(get_images, function(i,img){
 $('#container ul').append('<li><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="'+img+'"/></a></li>'); 
});
```

Comment: please put your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Or a just a sample in question would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
var get_images = ["show_1.jpg", "show_2.jpg", "show_3.jpg", "show_4.jpg"];
var original = $('#container ul').html();
$.each(get_images, function (i, img) {
    $('#container ul').append('<li><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="' + img + '"/></a></li>');
});
$("#revert").click( function() {
    $('#container ul').html(original);
});
```

The revert button is for demonstration purposes. The idea is basically that you save your original content so that you can revert back to it later if needed.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/48MAv/)

Answer (score 1):

If the `ul` was initially empty you can use `.empty()` to get it back to that state.

```
$('#container ul').empty()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about getting the last one you added and deleting it like this.:

```
 $('#container ul li:last').remove();
```

If you have added 3, then repeat that line 3 times. Each one gets the last added element and removes it.

---

**Another way**

You can also keep track of what is added with:

```
var addedList = [];

$.each(get_images, function(i,img){
    var added = $.parseHTML('<li><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="'+img+'"/></a></li>');
    $('#container ul').append(added);
    addedList.push(added);
});
```

Delete with something like:

```
for (var i=0; i < addedList.length; ++i) {
    $(addedList[i]).remove();
}
addedList = [];
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is in the right direction but I need to remove all of them not just the last.

Comment: parseHTML returns native DOM elements. Fixed it.